# Ime_option is changing automatically

Tags: java, android

My EditText `email_edittext` is changing the ime_option from `IME_ACTION_DONE` to `IME_ACTION_NEWLINE` newline means the arrow to make new line.

this is my code

```
email_edittext.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm =
                (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(SignupActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(email_edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Simply Don't open soft keyboard by force